# While trying to merge two linkedlist why am I getting segmentation fault(core dumped)?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault, malloc

So I was trying to merge two linked lists but I am getting a segmentation fault
The two linked lists were (1)->(2)->(3) and (1)->(3)->(4). The output remains the same even when I malloc `l` and `k`. The program works fine till the `merge` function is called. A little detailed explanation will help a lot as I am a beginner.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct linkedlist
{
    node *head;
    node *tail;
} linkedlist;

void createlinkedlist(linkedlist *l)
{
    l->head = NULL;
    l->tail = NULL;
}

void push(linkedlist *l, int value)
{
    node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (newnode == NULL)
    {
        printf("insertion failed");
        return;
    }
    newnode->val = value;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if (l->tail != NULL)
    {
        l->tail->next = newnode;
    }
    l->tail = newnode;
    if (l->head == NULL)
    {
        l->head = newnode;
    }
}

void display(linkedlist *l)
{
    node *printval = l->head;
    printf("\n");
    while (printval != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d-->", printval->val);
        printval = printval->next;
    }
}

void merge(linkedlist *l, linkedlist *k)
{
    node *lnext = l->head->next;
    node *lprevious = l->head;
    node *rprevious = k->head;
    node *rnext = k->head->next;
    if ((lprevious->val) <= (rprevious->val))
    {
        node *h = lprevious;
        while (lprevious != NULL && rprevious != NULL)
        {
            if (lprevious->val <= rprevious->val)
            {
                lprevious->next = rprevious;
                rprevious->next = lnext;
                rprevious = rnext;
                rnext = rnext->next;
                lprevious = lprevious->next;
            }
            else
            {
                lprevious = lprevious->next;
                lnext = lnext->next;
            }
        }
        l->head = h;
    }
    else
    {
        // node *h = head2;
        // while (previous != NULL || head2 != NULL) {
    }
}

int main()
{
    linkedlist l;
    linkedlist k;
    createlinkedlist(&l);
    createlinkedlist(&k);
    push(&l, 1);
    push(&l, 2);
    push(&l, 4);

    push(&k, 1);
    push(&k, 3);
    push(&k, 4);
    display(&k);
    display(&l);
    merge(&l, &k);
    display(&l);
}
```

The output which I am getting.

```
1-->3-->4-->
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And the worst part is my debugger is not showing any faults.

Comment: The debugger doesn't show which line of code causes the SIGSEGV? Hard to believe.

Comment: Hint: Start a 3rd (empty) LL in `merge()`... Append to it the node with the lowest value AFTER isolating that node from its list. When one list is exhausted, append the remainder of the other list to that 3rd (now full) LL... (Then you can tidy things up with the original pair of lists...) Trying to do this on the fly, as you've written, is complicated and error prone.

Comment: Not related to your immediate problem, but please get in the habit of writing all error messages to stderr: `fprintf(stderr, "insertion failed\n");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to merge lists in the ascending order.

Your function `merge` has several bugs.

The first one is that it does not take into account that in general one or both  lists passed to the function can be empty. In this case these statements in the beginning of the function

```
node *lnext = l->head->next;
node *rnext = k->head->next;
```

already invoke undefined behavior.

The same problem exists within the while loop in these statements

```
rnext = rnext->next;
lnext = lnext->next;
```

because pointers `rnext` and `lnext` can be null pointers.

Also there are logical errors in the if statement within the while loop.

At least if `lprevious->val` is not greater than `rprevious->val` it does not mean that you need to insert the node `rprevious` after the node `lprevious`.

```
if (lprevious->val <= rprevious->val)
{
    lprevious->next = rprevious;
    rprevious->next = lnext;
    rprevious = rnext;
    rnext = rnext->next;
    lprevious = lprevious->next;
}
else
{
    lprevious = lprevious->next;
    lnext = lnext->next;
}
```

On the other hand, if `lprevious->val` is greater than `rprevious->val` then it does not mean that you have to move to the second node `lprevious->next`.

And the function does not take into account the pointers `l->tail` and `r->tail` that it shall to change.

The function code will be more clear if at first just to form a new list based on the given two lists and then to set the first list to the formed list and to make the second list as an empty list.

Bear in mind that you need to write also a function that will free all the allocated memory for nodes of lists.

Also the parameter of the function `display` should have qualifier `const`

```
void display( const linkedlist *l)
```

because the function does not change passed lists.

And the function `push` should not display any message.

```
if (newnode == NULL)
{
    printf("insertion failed");
    return;
}
```

It is the caller of the function will decide whether to output a message. And moreover the caller of the function should have a possibility to know the result of a function call. That is the function should report to the caller a failure or a success through its return value.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the function `merge` can be implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct linkedlist
{
    node *head;
    node *tail;
} linkedlist;


int push( linkedlist *l, int value )
{
    node *newnode = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = newnode != NULL;

    if (success)
    {
        newnode->val = value;
        newnode->next = NULL;

        if (l->head == NULL)
        {
            l->head = newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            l->tail->next = newnode;
        }

        l->tail = newnode;
    }

    return success;
}

void merge( linkedlist *l, linkedlist *r )
{
    node *head = NULL;
    node *tail = NULL;

    node **current = &head;

    while (l->head != NULL && r->head != NULL)
    {
        if (r->head->val < l->head->val)
        {
            *current = r->head;
            r->head  = r->head->next;
        }
        else
        {
            *current = l->head;
            l->head  = l->head->next;
        }

        tail = *current;
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    if (l->head != NULL)
    {
        *current = l->head;
        tail = l->tail;
    }

    if ( r->head != NULL )
    {
        *current = r->head;
        tail = r->tail;
    }

    l->head = head;
    l->tail = tail;

    r->head = r->tail = NULL;
}

FILE *display( const linkedlist *l, FILE *fp )
{
    for (const node *current = l->head; current != NULL; current = current->next)
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", current->val );
    }

    fputs( "null", fp );

    return fp;
}

void clear( linkedlist *l )
{
    while (l->head)
    {
        node *current = l->head;
        l->head = l->head->next;
        free( current );
    }

    l->tail = l->head;
}

int main( void )
{
    linkedlist l = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2)
    {
        push( &l, i );
    }

    fputc( '\n', display( &l, stdout ) );

    linkedlist r = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2)
    {
        push( &r, i );
    }

    fputc( '\n', display( &r, stdout ) );

    putchar( '\n' );

    merge( &l, &r );

    fputc( '\n', display( &l, stdout ) );
    fputc( '\n', display( &r, stdout ) );

    clear( &l );
}
```

The program output is

```
0 -> 2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> null
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 7 -> 9 -> null

0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
null
```

And at last one more important remark. If you want to build sorted lists then the function `push`  should be rewritten to provide inserting new nodes in the ascending order.

In this case the function can look the following way

```
int push( linkedlist *l, int value )
{
    node *newnode = ( node * )malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = newnode != NULL;

    if (success)
    {
        newnode->val = value;

        node **current = &l->head;

        while (*current != NULL && !( newnode->val < ( *current )->val ))
        {
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }

        newnode->next = *current;
        *current = newnode;

        if ( newnode->next == NULL )
        {
            l->tail = newnode;
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: I see in the merge  funtion you have taken a Null pointer called head after all the operations been done it still stays as a null pointer and then you assign l->head = head . Can you give me a little bit of explaination on whats happening?

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation fault occurs because of a logical error in the merge function. Specifically, there are a few issues with the way the nodes are being linked together.

Here are the problems in the merge function:

The condition for checking if a node in the second linked list should be inserted into the first linked list is not correct. The condition should be (lprevious->val <= rprevious->val), but it's currently set as (lprevious->val) <= (rprevious->val). The extra parentheses are not necessary and cause the comparison to be incorrect.

The merge function is assuming that both linked lists are non-empty. However, there should be checks to handle the cases where one or both of the linked lists are empty.

The while loop in the merge function should continue as long as both lprevious and rprevious are not NULL. However, the loop's termination condition is based only on lprevious != NULL, which could lead to accessing NULL pointers for the second linked list if it is shorter than the first one.

The function is not correctly updating the tail pointer of the first linked list after the merge.

To fix these issues, you can update the merge function as follows:

```
void merge(linkedlist *l, linkedlist *k)
{
    node *lprevious = l->head;
    node *rprevious = k->head;

    // Check if either linked list is empty
    if (lprevious == NULL)
    {
        l->head = rprevious;
        l->tail = k->tail;
        return;
    }
    if (rprevious == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (lprevious->val > rprevious->val)
    {
        // Swap l and k pointers so that l always points to the smaller head
        linkedlist temp = *l;
        *l = *k;
        *k = temp;
    }

    node *lnext;
    node *rnext;

    while (lprevious != NULL && rprevious != NULL)
    {
        lnext = lprevious->next;
        rnext = rprevious->next;

        if (lnext == NULL || lnext->val > rprevious->val)
        {
            // Insert the node from the second list into the first list
            lprevious->next = rprevious;
            rprevious->next = lnext;
            rprevious = rnext;
        }
        lprevious = lprevious->next;
    }

    // Update the tail pointer of the first list if needed
    if (rprevious != NULL)
    {
        l->tail->next = rprevious;
        l->tail = k->tail;
    }
}
```

With these changes, the merge function should now work correctly. It correctly handles the cases when either linked list is empty, and it properly links the nodes from both linked lists together.

Now when you run the program, you should get the correct merged output for the linked lists:

1-->1-->2-->3-->4-->4-->

Comment: swapping the lists prevents stable merging: nodes with identical `val` fields in both lists will be merged in reverse order, which may not matter in this particular case but may pose problems in more general problems.

Comment: More problematic: `l->tail->next = rprevious;` is incorrect if an element of `k` was already inserted at the end of `l`. eg: merging `0` and `1->2` will produce the list `0->2` and the node `1` will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

The `merge` function has problems:

- `node *lnext = l->head->next;` has undefined behavior if `l` is an empty list because `l->head` is a null pointer.
- same problem for `node *rnext = k->head->next;`
- same problem with `if ((lprevious->val) <= (rprevious->val))`: if one of the lists is empty, `lprevious` or `rprevious` may be null pointers.
- similarly, `rnext = rnext->next;` and `lnext = lnext->next;` during the course of the `while` loop may cause undefined behavior as `lnext` and/or `rnext` may become null before the end of the loop. This is actually what is causing the segmentation fault you observe.

The `merge` function should insert any smaller elements from the head of `r` before the head of `l`, then iterate over `l` keeping a pointer to the previous element.

Here is a modified version:

```
void merge(linkedlist *l, linkedlist *k) {
    node *n = k->head;
    if (n == NULL) {
        // k is an empty list: nothing to do
        return;
    }
    if (l->head == NULL) {
        // l is an empty list: move all elements from k to l
        l->head = k->head;
        l->tail = k->tail;
        k->head = k->tail = NULL;
        return;
    }
    if (l->head->val > n->val) {
        // insert head element of k at head of l
        k->head = n->next;
        n->next = l->head;
        l->head = n;
    }
    node *prev = l->head;
    while ((n = k->head) != NULL) {
        if (prev->next == NULL) {
            // reached end of l: append all elements of k
            prev->next = n;
            l->tail = k->tail;
            break;
        }
        if (prev->next->val > n->val) {
            // insert node n between prev and prev->next
            k->head = n->next;
            n->next = prev->next;
            prev->next = n;
        }
        prev = prev->next;
    }
    // clear the k list
    k->head = k->tail = NULL;
}
```